# What is the difference between TryFrom<&[T]> and TryFrom<Vec<T>>?

Tags: rust

There seem to be two ways to try to turn a vector into an array, either via a slice (`fn a`) or directly (`fn b`):

```
use std::array::TryFromSliceError;
use std::convert::TryInto;

type Input = Vec<u8>;
type Output = [u8; 1000];

// Rust 1.47
pub fn a(vec: Input) -> Result<Output, TryFromSliceError> {
    vec.as_slice().try_into()
}

// Rust 1.48
pub fn b(vec: Input) -> Result<Output, Input> {
    vec.try_into()
}
```

Practically speaking, what's the difference between these? Is it just the error type? The fact that the latter was added makes me wonder whether there's more to it than that.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

They have slightly different behavior.

The slice to array [implementation](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.array.html#impl-TryFrom%3C%26%27_%20%5BT%5D%3E) will *copy* the elements from the slice. It has to copy instead of *move* because the slice doesn't *own* the elements.

The `Vec` to array [implementation](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.array.html#impl-TryFrom%3CVec%3CT%3E%3E) will *consume* the `Vec` and *move* its contents to the new array. It can do this because it does *own* the elements.

Comment: Also worth noting that for the `Vec` to array implementation, on failure it returns the input array as the error.