# What is the difference between the FromStr and TryFrom<String> traits?

Tags: string, rust, type-conversion

When working with the Serde crate in Rust I tried to add a `#[serde(try_from = String)]` [container attribute](https://serde.rs/container-attrs.html) to a type that implements `FromStr` and thus can be parsed from string. Unfortunately this seems not enough for Serde, from the compiler error message it becomes obvious that I have to manually implement `TryFrom<String>`, too.

Why is `TryFrom<String>` not implemented automatically for all types that implement `FromStr`? And why is there a separate trait for fallible conversion from strings? What is the difference between these two traits?

Comment: I think the answer is an average "for historical reasons": AFAIK `FromStr` is much older and `TryFrom` was added only later. However, the trait autoimplementation that you expected sounds logical, maybe there were technical reasons and it could not be easily done.

Comment: You might find it useful that `serde_with` allows you to [automatically (de)serialize using `FromStr` and `Display`](https://docs.rs/serde_with/1.8.1/serde_with/guide/serde_as/index.html#deserialize-with-fromstr-and-display), and has many other convenience features

Comment: Thanks for the link to `serde_with`. I will take a look, but as my project targets WASM I'm rather sensitive to additional dependencies in case they increase output size.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`FromStr` was stable in Rust 1.0, `TryFrom` was stablized in Rust 1.34; it would be very hard to use the trait before it existed.

> Why is `TryFrom<String>` not implemented automatically for all types that implement `FromStr`?

This would cause ambiguity with types that have already implemented both `TryFrom` and `FromStr`. An advanced form of *specialization* would be needed to allow this.

> why is there a separate trait for fallible conversion from strings?

`FromStr` creates an owned value from a borrowed string slice (`&str`), so it's semantically different from taking ownership of a `String`. `TryFrom<String>` would allow you to reuse the memory allocated for the `String`.

The closer analog would be `impl<'a> TryFrom<&'a str> for ...`, but having the lifetime in the trait makes using it more complicated in "simple" cases of parsing a value out of a string.

See also:

- [Should Rust implementations of From/TryFrom target references or values?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48244892/155423)
- [How is there a conflicting implementation of `From` when using a generic type?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37347311/155423)
- [What is the difference between TryFrom<&[T]> and TryFrom<Vec<T>>?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/65209340/155423)
- [How do I implement FromStr with a concrete lifetime?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28931515/155423)
- [What are reasons for FromStr trait not exposing lifetime?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30355949/155423)
- [How do I write the lifetimes for references in a type constraint when one of them is a local reference?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44343166/155423)

Comment: I should have noticed that both traits have different lifetime requirements. Implementing `TryFrom<&str>` and using `#[serde(try_from = "&str")]` seems to work fine, though.

Answer (score 1):

[`TryFrom`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/convert/trait.TryFrom.html) is a generic trait, which can be implemented for "any" type. From the documentation:

> Simple and safe type conversions that may fail in a controlled way under some circumstances.

`Type -> Type`

It also provides an auto implementation of [`TryInto`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/convert/trait.TryInto.html).

[`FromStr`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/str/trait.FromStr.html) is used mostly to parse types, also as per the documentation:

> FromStr's from_str method is often used implicitly, through str's parse method.

`str -> Type`

Implement it to be used by [`str::parse`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.str.html#method.parse)