# Is there any real difference between `FromStr` and `TryFrom<&str>`?

Tags: rust

Is there any real difference between `FromStr` and `TryFrom<&str>`?

From the definitions in the documentation, they look identical once you substitute `&str` for `T` in `TryFrom`:

```
pub trait FromStr {
    type Err;
    fn from_str(s: &str) -> Result<Self, Self::Err>;
}

pub trait TryFrom<T> {
    type Error;
    fn try_from(value: T) -> Result<Self, Self::Error>;
}
```

Then there is parse:

> FromStr’s from_str method is often used implicitly, through str’s
> parse method.

But if we look at its implementation, we see that it does not do anything beyond providing a slightly shorter way of calling `from_str`:

```
pub fn parse<F: FromStr>(&self) -> Result<F, F::Err> {
    FromStr::from_str(self)
}
```

If you look at TryFrom's library implementations, then it is almost exclusively composed of numerical conversions, though there is also:

```
impl<'_, T, const N: usize> TryFrom<&'_ [T]> for [T; N] where
    T: Copy, 
type Error = TryFromSliceError
```

which is reminiscent of

```
impl FromStr for String {
    type Err = core::convert::Infallible;
    #[inline]
    fn from_str(s: &str) -> Result<String, Self::Err> {
        Ok(String::from(s))
    }
}
```

Converting the example implementation of [FromStr from the docs](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/str/trait.FromStr.html#examples) to TryFrom [is trivial](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&code=use%20std%3A%3Aconvert%3A%3ATryFrom%3B%0Ause%20std%3A%3Anum%3A%3AParseIntError%3B%0A%0A%23%5Bderive(Debug%2C%20PartialEq)%5D%0Astruct%20Point%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20x%3A%20i32%2C%0A%20%20%20%20y%3A%20i32%0A%7D%0A%0Aimpl%20TryFrom%3C%26str%3E%20for%20Point%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20type%20Error%20%3D%20ParseIntError%3B%0A%0A%20%20%20%20fn%20try_from(s%3A%20%26str)%20-%3E%20Result%3CSelf%2C%20Self%3A%3AError%3E%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20let%20coords%3A%20Vec%3C%26str%3E%20%3D%20s.trim_matches(%7Cp%7C%20p%20%3D%3D%20%27(%27%20%7C%7C%20p%20%3D%3D%20%27)%27%20)%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20.split(%27%2C%27)%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20.collect()%3B%0A%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20let%20x_fromstr%20%3D%20coords%5B0%5D.parse%3A%3A%3Ci32%3E()%3F%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20let%20y_fromstr%20%3D%20coords%5B1%5D.parse%3A%3A%3Ci32%3E()%3F%3B%0A%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20Ok(Point%20%7B%20x%3A%20x_fromstr%2C%20y%3A%20y_fromstr%20%7D)%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%7D%0A%0Afn%20main()%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20let%20p%20%3D%20Point%3A%3Atry_from(%22(1%2C2)%22)%3B%0A%20%20%20%20assert_eq!(p.unwrap()%2C%20Point%7B%20x%3A%201%2C%20y%3A%202%7D%20)%0A%7D).

There was a [similar question on Reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/rust/comments/f55ur9/fromstr_vs_fromstr_vs_fromstring_which_should_i/) to which the best answer seems to be "just implement both".

Finally there is [this similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67385956/what-is-the-difference-between-the-fromstr-and-tryfromstring-traits) though it uses the wrong type and the Serde context is a distraction.

So:

1. Is there any real difference between `FromStr` and `TryFrom<&str>`?
2. What is current best practice regarding their use?
3. Is there any plan for the future towards improving the situation?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the difference between the FromStr and TryFrom<String> traits?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67385956/what-is-the-difference-between-the-fromstr-and-tryfromstring-traits)

Comment: @LeonardoDagnino The OP referred this question explicitly.

Comment: Sorry, didn't notice that. Does seem like the correct explanation to me.

Comment: *"Is there any plan for the future towards improving the situation?"* - I'm not sure anything needs to be changed. In general, there are cases where different traits will come down to the same implementation: see the overlap of `AsRef`, `Borrow`, and `Deref` for example. So just because the code looks the same doesn't mean they aren't designed for different generic use-cases. I think this particular case, `FromStr` probably *could* be subsumed by `TryFrom<&str>` in its entirety, but trying to change it now would probably be more effort than its worth.

Comment: @kmdreko AsRef, Borrow, and Deref have somewhat different use cases though. `FromStr` v `TryFrom` largely comes down to historical / timeline: `TryFrom` was added in 1.34.0 while `FromStr` is a 1.0 API (which can also be seen from `TryFrom::Err`).

Answer (score 2):

`FromStr` provides more type information to the compiler, and thus may help inference. It is also more specific, and thus helps the reader. When the intent is to parse the string, I would use `FromStr`, because it can be used via the `parse()` method. If this is just for conversion, I would implement `TryFrom<&str>`.

Also remember that as stated in [What is the difference between the FromStr and TryFrom<String> traits?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67385956/what-is-the-difference-between-the-fromstr-and-tryfromstring-traits), `FromStr` preceeded `TryFrom`.

> Is there any plan for the future towards improving the situation?

Nothing that I'm aware of.